# Extract text from textarea which was in between @ and # symbol

Tags: jquery, regex, textarea

I want to extract text from textarea which was in between @ and # symbol, for that am using below regular expression.

```
\B@(\w*)$/
```

However am not getting expected results when it has spaces in between delimiters.

For example

```
"Welcome to the company @first name last name# We all wished."
```

My output should be:

```
first name last name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`/@(.*?)#/`](https://regex101.com/r/sY8bJ6/2)** to match anything between `@` and `#`

```js
var str = "Welcome to the company @first name last name# We all wished.";
var res = str.match(/@(.*)#/)[1];
document.write(res);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var regex = /\@(.*?)\#/;
var str="Welcome to the company @first name last name# We all wished.";
var matched = regex.exec(str);
console.log(matched[1])
```